# What options are available to access R packages on AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: r, r-package, aws-codecommit

I developed an R package for internal use that I plan to host on AWS CodeCommit. I would like my teammates (who also have IAM access to CodeCommit) to be able to install the R package. Is there an equivalent to `devtools::install_github` that will work with a git repository on CodeCommit? Is `devtools::install_git` an option to use here?

Comment: You would need to explain to what "AWS CodeCommit" is. R's `install.packages()` as well as the `git` wrapper simply access https-reachable repositories, either code (see my `drat` package for creating some) or git.

Comment: I'm new to AWS CodeCommit, but it's described as a "source control service that hosts Git-based repositories." Since I clone repositories using https, I assume it is "https-reachable" with the right authentication settings. I will look into `drat`, it seems like it would be a good way to control the versioning vs `git`?

Comment: The R ecosystem generally relies on packages, which are tar.gz in source or related as binaries. `drat` helps with that.  If you AWS thingie is `git` based then the `git`-based wrapper in `remotes` (formerly `devtools`) is properly what you want. I and a few other people maintain that proper releases, identified as tarballs, have advantages over possibly more "random" git commit pulls.

Comment: I looked into `drat` and like the premise. However, I have issues using it with our filesystem. First, our directory has spaces, so I run into this issue: https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat/issues/22. When I provide the AWS url instead, I get this error  `In read.dcf(file = tmpf): cannot open compressed file '//company.awsapps.com/workdocs/index.html#/folder/793346937c/src/contrib/PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'` because AWS urls don't have the structure implied implied by "slash folder." Instead, the string after "folder/" is different. Next up I'll try `install_git`.

Comment: I have the same exact issue at hand. Did `remotes::install_git` work for you @missng? When I copied the https clone link and pass that to `remotes::install_git`, I get `Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from Git: Error in 'git2r_remote_ls'` https GRC also didn't work.

Comment: @LouSalome I did end up getting it work, but had issues setting up credentials so that I could access the repo through R. I ended up using this code `devtools::install_git("https://git-codecommit.loc.amazonaws.com/reponame", credentials = git2r::cred_user_pass("username", getPass::getPass()))` where you would replace the url with your repo's url. Credentials are then entered through a pop up.

I wonder if your error is related to credentials?